# In Jenkins, how to mirror a repository to another (using Git)?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Basically what I want to do is to mirror an open-source git repository to my own git repository.
The commands should be:

```
git clone --mirror target@github.com/target.git
cd target.git
git remote set-url --push origin %my_repo%
git fetch -p origin
git push --mirror
```

However,I couldn't find a way on Jenkins to perform commands above.
Could anyone show me the way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Github fork may be best but in Jenkins you can use the GitSCM plugin to reference a local bare copy.

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001728812-Using-a-Git-reference-repository

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.